# Tunnel Gre problem between two hosts (vps and dedicated server)

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, centos, tunnel

Hello guys i need to resolve this problem (all server have installed centos 7): i'm trying to create a gre tunnel through vps (in Italy - OpenVZ) and a dedicated server (in Germany), but they do not communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests). Next i create a gre tunnel trought vps (in Italy - OpenVZ) and vps (in France - KVM OpenStack) and their communicate, i next i had create a tunnel trought vps (in France - KVM OpenStack) and a dedicated server (in Germany) their communicate. I can not understand why the vps (in Italy - OpenVZ) and the dedicated server (in Germany) do not communicate, ideas on how I can fix (
I also tried with iptables disabled, firewalld is not enable)? Thanks

**In other words:**

In other attempts (by this i mean that i managed to successfully create the GRE Tunnel between these machines):

- The VPS (in France) and VPS (in Italy) communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests)
- The VPS (in France) and Dedicated Server (in Germany) communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests)

Problem (by this i mean that i could not successfully create the GRE Tunnel between these machines):

- The VPS (in Italy) and Dedicated Server (in Germany) do not communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests). I also asked hosting services if they had any restrinzione but nothing.

**My configuration:**

1. VPS command for tunnel:

   > echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
   >
   > iptunnel add gre1 mode gre local VPS_IP remote DEDICATED_SERVER_IP ttl 255
   >
   > ip addr add 192.168.168.1/30 dev gre1 ip link set gre1 up
2. Dedicated server command for tunnel:

   > iptunnel add gre1 mode gre local DEDICATED_SERVER_IP remote VPS_IP ttl 255
   >
   > ip addr add 192.168.168.2/30 dev gre1
   >
   > ip link set gre1 up

```
[root@VPS ~]# ping 192.168.168.2
PING 192.168.168.2 (192.168.168.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.168.2 ping statistics ---
89 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 87999ms
```

```
[root@DE ~]# ping 192.168.168.1
PING 192.168.168.1 (192.168.168.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.168.1 ping statistics ---
92 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 91001ms
```

```
[root@VPS ~]# tcpdump -i venet0 "proto gre" tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on venet0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes ^C 0 packets captured 1 packet received by filter 0 packets dropped by kernel
```

```
[root@DE ~]# tcpdump -i enp2s0 "proto gre" tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes ^C 0 packets captured 0 packets received by filter 0 packets dropped by kernel
```

```
[root@VPS ~]# lsmod | grep gre
ip_gre                  4242  -2
ip_tunnel               4242  -2 sit,ip_gre
gre                     4242  -2 ip_gre
```

```
[root@DE ~]# lsmod | grep gre
ip_gre                 22707  0
ip_tunnel              25163  1 ip_gre
gre                    13144  1 ip_gre
```

[Console image with full command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90b4U.png)

Answer (score 0):

If ip_forwarding is required for the tunnel to work, you need to do `/sbin/sysctl -p`
And what does the output of `ip tunnel show` and `ip route show` on both the ends

Comment: This is the screen with the full command including those you sent now : https://i.imgur.com/Ud91pip.png @Logu

Comment: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.tunnel.gre.html. The only difference seen here is the tunnel ip is from two different network and static  route is set to each other. You could try that.
Or setup a static host route to each other.
YOu could also try doing a `ip route flush cache`

Comment: Can you try stopping your firewall using this command `systemctl stop firewalld`. Assuming you are using Redhat based distribution.

Comment: The firewalld is disabled in both server and i'm running centos 7 @Logu. With this link "https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.tunnel.gre.html" i don't understand what i have to do on server, this is the output of console vps in Italy https://i.imgur.com/zJRXjIP.png and this is his ip 185.xx.xxx.xxx; This the output of dedicated server in germany https://i.imgur.com/jiFHFFL.png and his ip is 148.251.127.xx

Comment: These are the command https://i.imgur.com/hoOn7cE.png i tried with your guide, if I have understood well the guide then they have not worked. @Logu

Comment: In these cases, route to the tunneled network is missing as per you  i.imgur.com/zJRXjIP.png  and i.imgur.com/jiFHFFL.png.

The commands `ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev netb` on VPS and `ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 dev neta` on Server should have created the corresponding route on the vps and server which is missing. Are those commands executed without issues

Comment: I tried again and it does not work, here are the console output: 
- VPS: https://i.imgur.com/IzMePI2.png
- Dedicated Server: https://i.imgur.com/F24o8n8.png
@Logu

Comment: Ran out of ideas :(. You could try tcpdump as given here  https://serverfault.com/questions/684658/filtering-gre-enacpsulated-packets-with-tcpdump
Also check dmesg, /var/log/messages and audit logs for any weird messages

Comment: I tried again but nothing :( In both console i have this: <pre> tcpdump -ni any proto GRE && proto ICMP<br/>
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel </pre> @Logu

Comment: On messages log of Dedicated server i have this: https://pastebin.com/EziknKjE @Logu